# Ising Model in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, physics, montecarlo

I'm currently working on writing code for the Ising Model using Python3. I'm still pretty new to coding. I have working code, but the output result is not as expected and I can't seem to find the error. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import random


def init_spin_array(rows, cols):
    return np.random.choice((-1, 1), size=(rows, cols))


def find_neighbors(spin_array, lattice, x, y):
    left = (x , y - 1)
    right = (x, y + 1 if y + 1 < (lattice - 1) else 0)
    top = (x - 1, y)
    bottom = (x + 1 if x + 1 < (lattice - 1) else 0, y)

    return [spin_array[left[0], left[1]],
            spin_array[right[0], right[1]],
            spin_array[top[0], top[1]],
            spin_array[bottom[0], bottom[1]]]

def energy(spin_array, lattice, x ,y):
    return -1 * spin_array[x, y] * sum(find_neighbors(spin_array, lattice, x, y))


def main():
    lattice = eval(input("Enter lattice size: "))
    temperature = eval(input("Enter the temperature: "))
    sweeps = eval(input("Enter the number of Monte Carlo Sweeps: "))
    spin_array = init_spin_array(lattice, lattice)
    print("Original System: \n", spin_array)
    # the Monte Carlo follows below
    for sweep in range(sweeps):
        for i in range(lattice):
            for j in range(lattice):
                e = energy(spin_array, lattice, i, j)
                if e <= 0:
                spin_array[i, j] *= -1
            elif np.exp(-1 * e/temperature) > random.randint(0, 1):
                spin_array[i, j] *= -1
            else:
                continue
print("Modified System: \n", spin_array)

main()
```

I think the error is in the Monte Carlo Loop, but I am not sure. The system should be highly ordered at low temperatures and become disordered past the critical temperature of 2.27. In other words, the randomness of the system should increase as T approaches 2.27. For example, at T=.1, we should see large patches of spins that are aligned, i.e. patches of -1s and 1s. Past 2.27 the system should be disordered and we should not see these patches.

Comment: Give us an example of the output you want :) We're not all physicists here, so you'll have to translate what 'highly ordered at low temperature' looks like in terms of your expected output. Do you expect your spin array to have roughly the same values in each of its elements below 2.27 K?

Comment: Also, you may be interested in not reinventing the wheel and using [any one of these open-source already working implementations of the Ising model instead](https://github.com/search?l=Python&q=Ising&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93).

Comment: The randomness of the system should increase as T approaches 2.27. For example, at T=.1, we should see large patches of spins that are aligned, i.e. patches of -1s and 1s. Past 2.27 the system should be disordered and we should not see these patches.

Comment: Okay. Please edit the question to include that information :)

Comment: There appears to be an indentation error below `if e <= 0:`. I assume that the if-elif-else chain should all be indented, except for the first line. Also, is it correct that `spin_array[i, j]` does not get assigned/changed when both the if and elif conditions fail?

Comment: Ideally, you put in a bunch of print functions in the loop and print strategic variables, and see how they change over time (or better, you use a debugger, but print() is the simplest debugger there is). If you need a lot of loops to see the effect, just redirect the output to a file and examine that file at your leisure.

Answer (score 5):

Your question would make much more sense if you were to include the system size, the number of sweeps, and the average manetisation. How many of the intermediate configurations are ordered and how many disordered? MC is a sampling technique - individual configurations mean nothing and there might (and will) be disordered states at low temperature and ordered states at high T. It is the assembly properties (the average magnetisation) that is meaningful.

Anyway, there are three errors in your code: a small one, a medium one, and a really severe one.

The small one is that you are ignoring an entire row and an entire column while searching for neighbours in `find_neighbors`:

```
right = (x, y + 1 if y + 1 < (lattice - 1) else 0)
```

should be:

```
right = (x, y + 1 if y + 1 < lattice else 0)
```

or even better:

```
right = (x, (y + 1) % lattice)
```

Same applies to `bottom`.

The medium one is that your computation of the energy difference is off by a factor of two:

```
def energy(spin_array, lattice, x ,y):
   return -1 * spin_array[x, y] * sum(find_neighbors(spin_array, lattice, x, y))
          ^^
```

The factor is actually `2*J`, where J is the coupling constant, therefore having `-1` there means:

1. your critical temperature is halved, and more importantly...
2. you have **antiferromagnetic** spin interaction (J < 0), so no ordered states for you even at very low temperatures.

The worst mistake however is the use of `random.randint()` for the rejection sampling:

```
elif np.exp(-1 * e/temperature) > random.randint(0, 1):
    spin_array[i, j] *= -1
```

You should be using `random.random()` instead, otherwise the transition probability will always be 50%.

Here is a modification of your program that automatically sweeps over the temperature region from 0.1 to 5.0:

```
import numpy as np
import random


def init_spin_array(rows, cols):
    return np.ones((rows, cols))


def find_neighbors(spin_array, lattice, x, y):
    left   = (x, y - 1)
    right  = (x, (y + 1) % lattice)
    top    = (x - 1, y)
    bottom = ((x + 1) % lattice, y)

    return [spin_array[left[0], left[1]],
            spin_array[right[0], right[1]],
            spin_array[top[0], top[1]],
            spin_array[bottom[0], bottom[1]]]


def energy(spin_array, lattice, x ,y):
    return 2 * spin_array[x, y] * sum(find_neighbors(spin_array, lattice, x, y))


def main():
    RELAX_SWEEPS = 50
    lattice = eval(input("Enter lattice size: "))
    sweeps = eval(input("Enter the number of Monte Carlo Sweeps: "))
    for temperature in np.arange(0.1, 5.0, 0.1):
        spin_array = init_spin_array(lattice, lattice)
        # the Monte Carlo follows below
        mag = np.zeros(sweeps + RELAX_SWEEPS)
        for sweep in range(sweeps + RELAX_SWEEPS):
            for i in range(lattice):
                for j in range(lattice):
                    e = energy(spin_array, lattice, i, j)
                    if e <= 0:
                        spin_array[i, j] *= -1
                    elif np.exp((-1.0 * e)/temperature) > random.random():
                        spin_array[i, j] *= -1
            mag[sweep] = abs(sum(sum(spin_array))) / (lattice ** 2)
        print(temperature, sum(mag[RELAX_SWEEPS:]) / sweeps)


main()
```

And the result for 20x20 and 100x100 lattices and 100 sweeps:

[image: Average mangentisation as a function of the reduced temperature]

The starting configuration is a completely ordered one to prevent the development of domain walls that are very stable at low temperatures. Also, 30 additional sweeps are performed initially in order to thermalise the system (not nearly enough when close to the critical temperature, but the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm cannot properly handle the critical slowdown there anyway).